# куда идут деньги с покупок Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play

такой вопрос у меня одна программа в Google Play Console стоит она 56р его несколько раз купили не пойму а куда деньги идут на мою карту они не приходят ,и не нашел документацию связанное покупками ???

Comment: Очень хотелось ответить что деньги идут рокфеллеру через ЦРУ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Деньги находятся в личном кабинете консоли (см. пункт Настройки - Оплата) . 
Выплаты разработчикам совершаются 15-16 числа , каждого нового месяца.

Минимальный порог для выплаты 1$. Для того чтобы получать выплаты,

Вам необходимо заполнить платежный профиль в настройках консоли (см. пункт Настройки - Оплата) .
Доп. информация указана в Справке от самого гугла

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7161426?hl=ru